# Transformation from Screen Coordinates to World Coordinates in Opentk

Tags: c#

I am reading the screen coordinates through the UnProject function and they are read correctly when it is in an XY plane, however when I change to another plane the reading is not done correctly, the "Y" component is read as the "X" component of the point and the "X" component is completely wrong. Here my code.

```
void VistaEnElevacionYZ()
    {
        posicion = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        direccion = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        upZ = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        trX = -2.5f;
        trY = -2.5f;
        trZ = -1.0f;
        Escala3D = 0.35f;
    }
void SetupCamera()
    {
        Matrix4 lookAt = Matrix4.LookAt(posicion, direccion, upZ);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref lookAt); 
    }
public static PointF convertScreenToWorldCoords(float x, float y)
    {
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        Matrix4 modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, out modelViewMatrix);
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, out projectionMatrix);
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport);
        Vector2 mouse;
        mouse.X = x;
        mouse.Y = viewport[3] - y;
        Vector4 vector = UnProject(ref projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]), mouse);
        PointF coords = new PointF(vector.X, vector.Y);
        return coords;
    }
    
    public static Vector4 UnProject(ref Matrix4 projection, Matrix4 view, Size viewport, Vector2 mouse)
    {
        Vector4 vec;
        vec.X = 2.0f * mouse.X / (float)viewport.Width - 1;
        vec.Y = (2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height - 1);
        vec.Z = 0;
        vec.W = 1.0f;

        Matrix4 viewInv = Matrix4.Invert(view);
        Matrix4 projInv = Matrix4.Invert(projection);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref projInv, out vec);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref viewInv, out vec);

        if (vec.W > float.Epsilon || vec.W < float.Epsilon)
        {
            vec.X /= vec.W;
            vec.Y /= vec.W;
            vec.Z /= vec.W;
        }
        return vec;
    }
```

I call the method convertScreenToWorldCoords () from the MouseClick event and the VistaEnElevacionYZ method with the click event of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem that was the subject of my question. I did the calculation of my model matrix by direct multiplication of the transformations. I was also applying the translation before the scaling, for that reason my function did not work.

```
PointF convertScreenToWorldCoords(float x, float y)
    {
        Vector2 mouse;
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport);
        Matrix4 modelViewMatrix = (Matrix4.CreateTranslation(trX, trY, trZ) * Matrix4.CreateScale(Escala3D));
        Matrix4 projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(7.89f, 9.5f, 1.0f, 200f);

        mouse.X = x;
        mouse.Y = viewport[3] - y;
        Vector4 vector = UnProject(ref projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]), mouse);
        PointF coords = new PointF(vector.X, vector.Y);
        return coords;
    }
```